# MSSQL: When result of calculation is negative, return 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 colums:

- WarehouseStock (value 10)
- WarehouseReserved (value 20)

I want to get a zero when SELECT (WarehouseStock - WarehouseReserved) as Warehousetotal;

Is there a function or something that will convert negative numbers into 0?

Comment: Most DBMSes (but not SQL Server)  support `GREATEST(WarehouseStock - WarehouseReserved, 0)

Comment: Define a computed column or view with one of the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use "CASE" statement:

```
SELECT
   (CASE
      WHEN WarehouseStock - WarehouseReserved < 0 THEN 0
      ELSE WarehouseStock - WarehouseReserved 
    END) as Warehousetotal
FROM [your_table]
```

Another could be using `VALUE` and `MAX` functions:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT MAX(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (0), (WarehouseStock - WarehouseReserved)) AS VALUE(v)) as Warehousetotal
FROM [your_table]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case` expression is what you use if you want your intent to be obvious.  If you want inscrutable code, you could use:

```
select (WarehouseStock - WarehouseReserved) * (sign(WarehouseStock - WarehouseReserved) + 1) / 2
```